# How to update local copy of content with Laravel API only when there is update in data

Tags: android, laravel, flutter

I'm developing a mobile app using Flutter and it's backed using Laravel. For each page, I'm making a request. Since the page content doesn't change that often I'm thinking to store a copy of content locally on phone and update it weekly. But the issue is that the data can change more often.
Is it possible for Laravel to notify when there is a data change, and start the sync?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be possible for the backend to update the front end for every instance of the app.

Instead you could do a specific route like

```
Route::get('/recently-updated', 'APIController@recentlyUpdated')
```

Then in your controller

```
public function recentlyUpdated() {

$updatedAt = Page::orderBy('CREATED_AT', 'desc')->get()->updated_at;

return $updatedAt;

}
```

And just store that in your app and compare them. Maybe have it checked on launch or at x interval.

This is not the only way but a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I still would have to make requests to check if the data has changed. Can I implement anything better by using Laravel's Notifications ?

Comment: There is no way to notify the app on the device unless you have a way to reach it. So the app has to do the work. Why is that an issue? It would have to pull the data anyways. You could send the timestamp from the app to the server and return the new pages if you're worried about the number of calls. If there are no new pages then return null.